# In R, extract all substrings of a certain length or longer

Tags: r

I have a string that I am working with:

```
peptide <- "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSED"
```

It is 115 characters in length.

I would like to extract all substrings of 60 character or longer from this string.

If I use:

```
substring(peptide, first = 1:60, last = (115-60):115)
```

it doesn't take all combinations, as I had hoped.  Not sure how to capture all of the combinations.

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse` you can do something like this

```r
peptide <- "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSED"

library(tidyverse)
combn(seq_len(nchar(peptide)), 2) %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% filter(V2 - V1 >= 60) -> df

all_desired_substrings <- substring(peptide, df$V1, df$V2)

head(all_desired_substrings)
#> [1] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDP"     
#> [2] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPR"    
#> [3] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRY"   
#> [4] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRYA"  
#> [5] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRYAI" 
#> [6] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQDIQNDPRYAIL"

tail(all_desired_substrings)
#> [1] "RWQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMS"  
#> [2] "RWQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSE" 
#> [3] "RWQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSED"
#> [4] "WQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSE"  
#> [5] "WQDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSED" 
#> [6] "QDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAYLNMSED"
```

---

translating above code to baseR

```
apply(t(combn(seq_len(nchar(peptide)), 2))[combn(seq_len(nchar(peptide)), 2,  FUN = function (x) x[2] - x[1] >= 60),], 1, 
        FUN = function(y) substring(peptide, y[1], y[2]))
```

- Both above code return `1540 substrings`

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap `substring()` in a function and put it into `outer()`. Assign appropriate `` `dimnames<-`() `` dimnames at the same time.

```
FUN <- function(x, y) substring(peptide, first=x, last=y)

m <- 1:60  ## rows
n <- (115 - 60):115  ##columns

r <- `dimnames<-`(outer(m, n, FUN), list(m, n))
```

This gives you a matrix

```
dim(r)
# [1] 60 61
```

which schematically looks like this:

```
# 55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64 ... 110 111 112 113 114 115
# 1  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# 2  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# 3  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# 4  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# 5  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# 6  "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" 
# ...
# 10 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 55 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 56 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 57 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 58 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 59 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
# 60 "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" ... "X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "X"
```

With the underlying logic you can easily access the matrix elements

```
r[55, 115 - 60]
# [1] "QDIQNDPRYAILNEPFKGEMNRGNFLEIKNKFLARRFKLLEQALVIEEQLRRAAY"
```

or alternatively treat it like a vector.

```
r[1:10]
# [1] "FMFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ" "MFNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ" 
# [3] "FNIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"   "NIADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"   
# [5] "IADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"     "ADGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"     
# [7] "DGGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"       "GGFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"       
# [9] "GFTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"         "FTELHSLWQNEERAATVTKKTYEIWHRRHDYWLLAGIINHGYARWQ"
```